# Jasmine-Node only running first test

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am currently attempting to run some tests on my NodeJs Application, however only the first test runs. (I know this as the last test is designed to fail as it is yet to be implimented). Here are my tests.

```
'use strict'
const request = require('request')
const base_url = 'http://localhost:8080'
const search_url = 'http://localhost:8080/search?q=pizza'
const recipe_url = 'http://localhost:8080/recipe/516818'

const index = require('../index.js')
const SuccessCode = 200

describe('GetData Test',function(){

    describe('Get /', function() {
        it('returns statusCode 200', function(done) {
            request.get(base_url, function(error, response){
                expect(response.statusCode).toBe(SuccessCode)
                done()
            })

        })
        it('returns Api is Online', function(done) {
            request.get(base_url, function(error, response, body){
                expect(body).toBe('"Api is online"')
                done()
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Get search/', function() {
        it('returns statusCode 200', function(done) {
            request.get(search_url, function(error, response){
                expect(response.statusCode).toBe(SuccessCode)
                done()
            })

        })
        it('returns JSON containing the Search Term', function(done) {
            request.get(search_url, function(error, response, body){
            expect(body).toContain(pizza) //eslint-disable-line
                done()
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Get recipe/',function(){
        it('returns statusCode 200', function(done) {
            request.get(recipe_url, function(error, response){
                expect(response.statusCode).toBe(SuccessCode)
                done()
            })
        })
        it('returns JSON containing Steps', function(done) {
            request.get(recipe_url, function(error, response, body){
                expect(body.title).toContain(pizza) //eslint-disable-line
                done()
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it, Needed to use Jasmine istead of jasmine-node